# Execution stuck at printf -- assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, gdb, x86-64

I am modifying some assembly code to do a printf. The first time the printf is called, its working perfectly. But on the second time, it is getting suck at the call to printf. I am using gdb to debug.

The original partial code is

```
    movq    192(%rsp), %rax         # 8-byte Reload
    movq    (%rax), %rcx
    movq    200(%rsp), %rdx         # 8-byte Reload
    movq    (%rdx), %rsi
    movq    %rcx, %rdi
    movq    24(%rsp), %r8           # 8-byte Reload
    addq    %r8, %rdi
    movq    $0, (%rsi)
    movq    216(%rsp), %r9          # 8-byte Reload
    movq    (%r9), %r10
    movq    208(%rsp), %r11         # 8-byte Reload
    movq    (%r11,%rdi,8), %rbx
```

The modified code is

```
    movq    192(%rsp), %rax         # 8-byte Reload
    movq    (%rax), %rcx
    movq    200(%rsp), %rdx         # 8-byte Reload
    movq    (%rdx), %rsi
    movq    %rcx, %rdi
    movq    24(%rsp), %r8           # 8-byte Reload
    addq    %r8, %rdi
    pushq   %rax
    pushq   %rsi
    pushq   %rdi
    movq    %rsi, %rax
    movl    $.LCdddd, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    popq    %rdi
    popq    %rsi
    popq    %rax
    movq    $0, (%rsi)
    movq    216(%rsp), %r9          # 8-byte Reload
    movq    (%r9), %r10
    movq    208(%rsp), %r11         # 8-byte Reload
    movq    (%r11,%rdi,8), %rbx
```

when I do a `Ctrl + C` in gdb when it getting stuck it is showing it is in

```
__lll_lock_wait_private () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:93
```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: The gdb trace is as follows. After the last line it simply waiting

```
196     movq    %rsi, %rax
(gdb) 
197     movl    $.LCdddd, %edi
(gdb) 
198     movl    $0, %eax
(gdb) 
199     call    printf
(gdb) 
__printf (format=0x40969e "\nmeow %p\n") at printf.c:30
30  printf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) s
34  in printf.c
(gdb) s
30  in printf.c
(gdb) s
35  in printf.c
(gdb) s
34  in printf.c
(gdb) 
35  in printf.c
(gdb) 
_IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x7ffff7ba8280 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, format=0x40969e "\nmeow %p\n", ap=0x7fffffffdfc0) at vfprintf.c:246
246 vfprintf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
211 in vfprintf.c
(gdb) 
246 in vfprintf.c
(gdb) 
1298    in vfprintf.c
(gdb) 
1302    in vfprintf.c
(gdb) 
1313    in vfprintf.c
(gdb) 
1324    in vfprintf.c
(gdb) 
1335    in vfprintf.c
(gdb) 
__find_specmb (format=<optimized out>) at printf-parse.h:99
99  printf-parse.h: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
_IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x7ffff7ba8280 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, format=0x40969e "\nmeow %p\n", ap=0x7fffffffdfc0) at vfprintf.c:1324
1324    vfprintf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
1335    in vfprintf.c
(gdb) 
__find_specmb (format=0x40969e "\nmeow %p\n") at printf-parse.h:99
99  printf-parse.h: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
strchrnul () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S:27
27  ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
28  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
29  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
30  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
31  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
32  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
33  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
34  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
35  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
36  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
37  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
38  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
39  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
40  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
41  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
42  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
43  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
44  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
45  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
46  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
48  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
49  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
50  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
51  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
52  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
53  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
54  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
55  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
56  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
58  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
59  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
strchrnul () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S:60
60  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S
(gdb) 
_IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x7ffff7ba8280 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, format=0x40969e "\nmeow %p\n", ap=0x7fffffffdfc0) at vfprintf.c:1339
1339    vfprintf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
1335    in vfprintf.c
(gdb) 
__find_specmb (format=0x40969e "\nmeow %p\n") at printf-parse.h:99
99  printf-parse.h: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
_IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x7ffff7ba8280 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, format=0x40969e "\nmeow %p\n", ap=0x7fffffffdfc0) at vfprintf.c:1339
1339    vfprintf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
_pthread_cleanup_push_defer (buffer=0x7fffffffde78, routine=0x7ffff784cf70 <__funlockfile>, arg=0x7ffff7ba8280 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at cleanup_defer_compat.c:31
31  cleanup_defer_compat.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
32  in cleanup_defer_compat.c
(gdb) 
33  in cleanup_defer_compat.c
(gdb) 
35  in cleanup_defer_compat.c
(gdb) 
38  in cleanup_defer_compat.c
(gdb) 
55  in cleanup_defer_compat.c
(gdb) 
57  in cleanup_defer_compat.c
(gdb) 
58  in cleanup_defer_compat.c
(gdb) 
_IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x7ffff7ba8280 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, format=0x40969e "\nmeow %p\n", ap=0x7fffffffdfc0) at vfprintf.c:1340
1340    vfprintf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff783d325 in _L_lock_927 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) 
Single stepping until exit from function _L_lock_927,
which has no line number information.
__lll_lock_wait_private () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:77
77  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
79  in ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S
(gdb) 
83  in ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S
(gdb) 
84  in ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S
(gdb) 
85  in ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S
(gdb) 
87  in ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S
(gdb) 
88  in ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S
(gdb) 
93  in ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S
(gdb) 
94  in ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S
(gdb) 
96  in ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S
(gdb) 
97  in ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S
(gdb) 
90  in ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, printf has CCALL calling convention. So, you probably have to remove the pushed arguments manually from the stack, after printf returns.

Comment: I assume this is Linux x86-64 assembly and thus follows System V ABI, so the arguments are in registers `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `rcx`, `r8`, `r9`, not in stack.

Comment: Yes, but AFAIK, printf supports variable count of arguments. Some of them (or all of them, I am not sure - it depends on the C compiler) must be passed through the stack.

Comment: The function is working properly when it is called first time, so I dont think it is the problem with arguments. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Debian : If the function is working properly the first time, then something goes wrong after its returning. Not cleaned stack is very common reason for such kind of bugs, especially if you are using imported C functions. (generally speaking, IMHO, using C functions from assembly is a bad practice)

Comment: @johnfound I am doing this for debugging some other code :). In the code above, I have not pushed and popped stack. Is that necessary?

Comment: @Debian BTW, try to set break point (int3 instruction) just before printf call and then try to follow what happens with the stack before and after printf call executing the program step by step. Some visual debugger should be more helpful in this case.

Comment: @johnfound The first time the stack pointer remains same. (I cannot check the second time as it is getting suck over there)

Comment: @Debian - What about the registers?

Comment: @Debian Try to check what registers printf changes (besides of rax, rsi and rdi which you already saved) and then push/pop them as well. As long as you are trying to insert your code inside compiler generated code, you simply must preserve everything, because what registers the compiler uses is unknown.

Comment: @johnfound I will do that. There is no pusha equivalent instruction in x86_64 right? Also printf is supposed to preserve the value of registers right?

Comment: @Debian I am not sure printf is supposed to preserve all registers used. It is not true for STDCALL, nor for CCALL calling conventions. I don't know about x86-64.

Comment: @johnfound I checked the registers. They seems to correct. I have no idea what is wrong. But for now I will use gdb for analysis so that I can print the values. Thankyou for your time

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed stack protection. Try __printf_chk instead, along with saving your frame and restoring it, like:

```
pushq %rbp
movq  %rsp, %rbp
pushq   %rax
pushq   %rdx
pushq   %rsi
pushq   %rdi
xorl  %edx, %edx
movl  $.LCdddd, %esi
movl  $1, %edi
xorl  %eax, %eax
call  __printf_chk
popq   %rdi
popq   %rsi
popq   %rdx
popq   %rax
leave
```

__printf_chk is non-standard, but must be in libc. Vararg functions are sometimes tricky. With checked printf you will be at least warned.

```
movl  $1, %edi
```

is flag value (see [something like specification](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/libc---printf-chk-1.html)), so you may experiment with passing 2, or greater. Since this is non-standard feature, hard to say what will you see on your system.

Comment: now its working and printing a 0 value. But in the second run it is causing some seg faults

Comment: also why is rbp not poped at the end?

Comment: Can you run under valgrind? I mean, even if __printf_chk corrupts stack, we are returning frame. May be stack is corrupted somewhere else?

Comment: 64-bit leave restores rsp from rbp and pops rbp. It is just shorter form.

Comment: If I remove the added statements it working properly. So I dont think some other instruction is corrupting it.